# Are Node.js 4.0 scripts not modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6

In Node 4.0, when you execute a script from the command line, the script is wrapped (in a function) in such a way that `this` does not refer to the global object.

```
[~]$ cat global.js
console.log(this===global);
[~]$ node -v
v4.0.0
[~]$ node global.js 
false
```

Fair enough. In fact, there have been quite a few Stack Overflow questions addressing this. It makes total sense and is proper.

What I did *not* expect was this:

```
[~]$ cat x.js
let x=10;
[~]$ node x.js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let x=10;
                                                          ^^^
```

In the [ES2015 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) it says that "Module code is always strict mode code."

So am I to understand that code executed by Node.js as a script is not a "module"? If it's not a module, what is it? How is one supposed to distinguish between module code and non-module code? Or is it the case that Node is still catching up to the standard? Section 15 of the standard ("Scripts and Modules") is either unclear on the difference between scripts and modules, or I missed something very obvious.

Is something only a "module" when imported? (Like the way one uses `$0` and `__FILE__` in ruby and `__name__` and `"__main__"` in Python?) Seems a shame to have to use `"use strict"` all the time in scripts.

Comment: node.js code is not an ES2015 module.  It's a commonJS module.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: The Module ES2015 talking about is different from Node.js modules

Comment: See the use-strict module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-strict.  It would be nice if this was a built-in global option, though there could still be NPM modules people are using that might have errors if forced into `"use strict";` though it would be nice to force them to clean up their act.

Comment: I've been using babel for a while and it gives us `"use strict"` for free. You also get the ES2015 module syntax (e.g. `import x from "x"`) which Node 4 doesn't yet seem to import. But why is babel placing `use strict` even at the beginning of plain scripts if these are not ES2015 modules? Is it just because node wants to continue with CommonJS modules (yes I read [Rauschmayer's great article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)). I thought the ES2015 modules were compatible with the existing CommonJS ones. So they're not?

Comment: *"why is babel placing use strict even at the beginning of plain scripts if these are not ES2015 modules?"* Babel assumes that every file is a module. *"I thought the ES2015 modules were compatible with the existing CommonJS ones"* Compatible in which way? They use completely different syntax for importing and exporting!

Comment: Okay maybe "compatible" was not a good choice of words, but I was hoping that Node 4.0 would follow Babel's lead. Babel transpiles ES2015 import statements into require calls. It is super convenient. Using `import x from 'm'` or `import {x,y} from m` in your ES2015 code in babel and having it automatically require was just nice. With Node 4 that doesn't work and I feel like I'm losing something. Did Babel just spoil us? Seems like those 500,000 npm modules should be accessible via ES2015 imports. Too much to ask?

Comment: You can still use Babel with Node 4 and do that.

Comment: Thank you, I will continue to use Babel. I was just disappointed though, because there are hundreds of thousands of npm modules that already use require.js, and the fact that they may be incompatible with (in the sense that ES2015 modules are not CommonJS modules) the new import syntax (when it arrives in Node) would be sad. Hopefully when node gets the new syntax it will be able to read the existing npm modules the way Babel can. I so wanted to drop Babel for simplicity but at the moment it's far simpler to keep it. :)